A is self-adjoint and $\|Ax\|=\|A\|$. Show x is an eigenvector for $A^2$.
Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and let $A$ be a bounded self-adjoint operator on $H$. Suppose that there exists a unit vector $x \in H$ such that $||Ax||=||A||$.
i) Show that $x$ is an eigenvector of $A^2$ corresponding to eigenvalue $||A||^2$.
ii) Show that either $Ax = ||A||x$ or $Az=-||A||z$ for some unit vector $z$.
$\textbf{Attempt.}$
For part i), I am able to show that $\langle A^2x,x \rangle - ||A||^2 = 0$ but I am unsure how to proceed with this fact. I wanted to claim that,
\begin{align*}
 \langle A^2x,x \rangle - ||A||^2 &= \langle A^2x,x \rangle - ||A||^2 \langle x,x\rangle \\ &=\langle A^2x - ||A||^2x, x\rangle,
\end{align*}
and so if it equals to 0, then the first component must equal to 0 and thus $A^2x = ||A||^2x$, but I do not think I can just claim that the first component must equal to 0 this easily.
For part ii), I have no idea.
Any guidance on both parts would be appreciated!

@geetha290krm I am able to prove that. How does that help conclude that $A^2x = ||A||^2x$?

$A$ is self-adjoint, so $A^2$ is self-adjoint as well. By spectral theorem, as $|A^2| \leq |A|^2$, we have $|A|^2 - A^2$ is positive. For any positive operator $B$, $\langle Bx, x \rangle = 0$ implies $Bx = 0$.

@DavidGao I see. Why is it that if $B$ is positive that $\langle Bx, x\rangle =0$ implies $Bx=0$?

@Aester If $B$ is positive, by spectral theorem there exists a self-adjoint square root $B^{1/2}$. Then,$$|B^{1/2}x|^2 = \langle B^{1/2}x, B^{1/2}x \rangle = \langle Bx, x \rangle = 0$$So $B^{1/2}x = 0$ and thus $Bx = B^{1/2}B^{1/2}x = 0$.

@DavidGao Thank you, that clears up part i)!

@Aester For part (ii), this is again spectral theorem. Any eigenvector of $A^2$ with eigenvalue $|A|^2$ is an eigenvector of $|A| = (A^2)^{1/2}$ with eigenvalue $|A|$, which in turn must be a linear combination of eigenvectors of $A$ with eigenvalue $|A|$ and eigenvectors of $A$ with eigenvalue $-|A|$. So either there is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $-|A|$, in which case you get the required $z$, or there is no eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $-|A|$, in which case $x$ must be an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $|A|$.

Since you want to show $A^{2}x-||A||^{2}x=0$, what you need to do is check what happens to
$$\langle A^{2}x-||A||^{2}x \,,\, A^{2}x-||A||^{2}x\rangle$$
See that you get \begin{align} \langle A^{2}x-||A||^{2}x \,,\, A^{2}x-||A||^{2}x\rangle=&\langle A^{2}x,A^{2}x\rangle+||A||^{4}-2\cdot||A||^{2}\langle A^{2}x,x\rangle\\\\
&=||A^{2}x||^{2}+||A||^{4}-2||A||^{2}\langle Ax,Ax\rangle\\\\
&\leq ||A^{2}||^{2}+||A||^{4}-2||A||^{4}\\\\
&\leq 0\end{align}
where we have used that for any operator, $||T^{n}||\leq ||T||^{n}$. This shows that $(A^{2}-||A||^{2}I)x =0$ which means $(A+||A||I)(A-||A||I)x=0$ .
If $(A-||A||I)x\neq 0$, then let $y=(A-||A||I)x$.
Then $(A+||A||I)y=0$ implies $z:=\frac{y}{||y||}$ is such that $Az=-||A||z$
Otherwise, if $(A-||A||I)x=0$, then $Ax=||A||x$
NOTE:-Essentially this is main step in the proof of the finite dimensional spectral theorem. The existence of $x$ such that $||Ax||=||A||$ is guaranteed by the fact that the function $f:\Bbb{S}^{n-1}\to\Bbb{K}$ defined by $f(x)=||Ax||$ achieves it's supremum, i.e. $||A||$ for some $x$ lying on the unit sphere. This is because any continuous function defined on a compact subset of $\Bbb{K}^{n}$ achieves it's supremum and infinmum at some points in the subset.  After you have that $||A||$ or $-||A||$ is an eigen value, you just have to apply an easy induction argument to get a basis of eigen vectors for $A$.

WLOG we may assume $\|A\|=1.$ If $\|Ax\|=1$ for $\|x\|=1,$ then $$1=\|Ax\|^2=\langle A^2x,x\rangle \le \|A^2x\|\|x\|\le 1\ (*)$$ We get the equality in the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, hence $A^2x=\lambda x.$ By $(*)$ we obtain $\lambda=1,$ i.e. $A^2x=x.$ We have $$ A(Ax- x)=-(Ax-x)$$ Therefore if $Ax\neq x$ then $Az=-z$ for $z=Ax-x.$
